# how to get the data from the mysql database where date is between the value of 2 datetimepicker

Tags: mysql, vb.net

im using vb.net 2008 and mysql in xampp. i have two datetimepicker from form7. when the "display report button" is click then the summary form will show.it contains the datagridview that contains the informations. im trying to get the data from the database where the date_drop is between the value of two datetimepicker. Hope you can help me. Thanks in Advance :) 
--here's my code for that but it doesnt give any data :(

```
ct = "Select j_id as 'Job Code', 
             cus_name as 'Customer Name',
             date_drop as 'Date Drop'
       from jobs 
      where date_drop between '" & DateTimePicker2.Value & "'
                          and '" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "' "
```

Comment: Which datepicker contains the end date?  Notice that mySQL requires `BETWEEN start AND end`.

Comment: Check the format of datetimepicker.value, and run the same Query in MySQL console, if that gives you data, then you are fine.

Comment: @ollie Jones - the datetimepicker1 will be the start and the datetimepicker2 will be the end.

Comment: i have tried almost all of the codes i have seen here but still it doesnt give any data

Comment: thanks @ollie jones the datagridview is now giving me values. but i have a problem again. the start date is 09/21/2014 and the most recent is 10/19/2014. when i set the start date in datetimepicker 08/30/2014 or lower and the end date in 10/01/2014 it gives me all the data. but when i set it in same month or month is 09 it doesnt give any data. hope you can help me. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You mention datepicker1 is the start time and datepicker2 the end time.

So, *even if the values from your datepickers are formatted correctly for presentation to MySQL*, your query ends up saying something like

```
BETWEEN '2014-09-28' AND '2014-09-26'
```

There are no dates in that range; you need to provide the start date first in the `BETWEEN` clause, like so

```
BETWEEN '2014-09-26' AND '2014-09-28'
```

See how the earlier date comes first?

In actual fact, you'd be wise to use this formulation instead

```
 where date_drop >= '" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "'
   and date_drop <  '" & DateTimePicker2.Value & "' + INTERVAL 1 DAY "
```

That gets the two ends of the range in the right order. It also works in cases where `date_drop` might not be precisely at midnight on the end date.

Comment: i have tried the code but the still the datagridview doesnt give any data.

Comment: thanks @ollie jones the datagridview is now giving me values. but i have a problem again. the start date is 09/21/2014 and the most recent is 10/19/2014. when i set the start date in datetimepicker 08/30/2014 or lower and the end date in 10/01/2014 it gives me all the data. but when i set it in same month or month is 09 it doesnt give any data. hope you can help me. thanks :)